# PHP - Minue sign with GET query in laravel redirecting to different page

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I noticed a strange behavior of redirecting URL having '-' sign in it to a different URL. If I remove that - sign it open page properly. Following is the URL:

https://thegreatinflatablerace.com/Coachella-Valley

If you hit that URL it will redirect you to:

https://thegreatinflatablerace.com/newevent/Coachella-Valley

and if you noticed the second URL also include '-' sign in it. This is Laravel framework and below are the routes for the above two:

```
Route::get('/newevent/{cityName}', ['as' => 'newevent', 'uses' => 'Frontend\EventsController@newevent']);
Route::get('/{cityName}', ['as' => 'event', 'uses' => 'Frontend\EventsController@index']);
```

Comment: i was not redirected. no problem

Comment: @FatemehMajd that's strange me and my client are redirecting..